# How to listen for a socket input without blocking other requests

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

My title is probably not the most descriptive, but I'm going to try and show as much code as possible in hope that it'll help everyone understand my question better. Here's how my client side of my project queries the server for information. This is an example of a typical request:

```
private String GENERATEGROUPKEY()
{
    /* `out` is a PrintWriter using the sockets output stream */
    out.println("GENERATEGROUPKEY");

    try
    {
        /* `in` is a BufferedReader using the sockets input stream */
        String response = in.readLine();
        String[] temp = response.split(" ");

        return temp[1];
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        return null; // throw connection error to client
    }
}
```

My issue is that at any time, the server can send an unsolicited message to the client through that same socket with information (think about it like a chat client receiving a message). My unsuccessful idea was to create a thread that listens for such a message as long as we're not in the middle of another query, but that was also unsuccessful because even though I'm interrupting that thread, it's still hogging the messages that should've gone to the client query.

```
private String GENERATEGROUPKEY()
{
    out.println("GENERATEGROUPKEY");
    listenThread.interrupt(); // block listenThread from recieving response

    try
    {
        String response = in.readLine();
        String[] temp = response.split(" ");

        listenThread = new PulseThread(in); // we're done, so allow 
        listenThread.start();
        return temp[1];
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        listenThread = new PulseThread(in); // we're done, so allow
        listenThread.start(); 
        return null; // throw connection error to client
    }
}
```

Here's exactly what `listenThread` is

```
public class PulseThread extends Thread
{
    private BufferedReader in;

    public PulseThread(BufferedReader in)
    {
        this.in = in;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
            {
                break;
            }
            try
            {
                String line = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(line);
                String[] params = line.split(" ");
                if (params[0].equals("PULSED"))
                {
                    NotificationManager.sendNotification("You have been pulsed!", "Pulsed by: " + params[1]);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was previously under the impression that interrupting the thread in the middle of the `BufferedReader`'s blocking call with `readLine()` would just cancel the blocking call unless I'm doing something else wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: So looking into my assumption just a few lines above this sentence, it seems interrupting the thread doesn’t cancel `readLine()`. I guess the interrupting thread idea is a no-go. What’s the right way to do this?

Comment: With, err, [tag:multithreading]? And where does it say that interrupting a thread will cancel the I/O operation it is blocked in?

Comment: @EJP Is this not a multi threading question? Not sure if the -1 on a legitimate and unique question was appropriate, but I digress. Javadocs say, and I quote, "If this thread is blocked in an I/O operation upon an interruptible channel then the channel will be closed." Does this not apply to me? If not what're my possible solutions because I am unaware of what I need to do.

Comment: @Headline The actual quote says [InterruptibleChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/InterruptibleChannel.html) as in a java class. BufferedReader *might* be throwing an exception, but as you aren't doing anything with it, you wouldn't know.

Comment: Also, if you are using a channel, and you interrupt the thread that is reading from it and it closes that channel... nothing else gets to read from that channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general pattern here is that you want one thread processing output from the socket (blocking while waiting) and then dispatching messages out to the correct things that requested them.

One implementation I like and have used successfully in multiple projects is to add a randomly generated ID to “requests” as part of a generic header (including a message type as well) and have the server always mirror the ID back in the response, which allows the client to associate a request with a response without caring what type of message it is.

In concrete terms, something like a `SocketMessenger` class with 2 public functions: `sendRequest(type, body, callback)` and `registerUnsolicitedHandler(type, callback)`.

`sendRequest` builds the message header with `type` and a randomly generated ID, adds it to a list of pending replies alongside a reference to the callback function, and then sends the completed message to the server.

`registerUnsolicitedHandler` does what it’s name suggests and adds the callback function to a map of message types to be used when an incoming message has no ID.

In the separate thread handling incoming messages, it deserialises incoming data to get the type and ID from the header, if the message has an ID it searches the pending reply list and calls the appropriate callback with the message body (probably scheduled on the main thread, I’m glossing over some detail like locking), else it searches the unsolicited handler list for the specified type and calls that callback.